# Когда нужна постановка "- это"?

Tags: орфография, синтаксис

Существует ли закрепление в правилах связки **"- это"** в конструкция типа: 
"Порядок слов в предложении *– это* взаимное расположение членов предложения, имеющее синтаксическое, смысловое и стилистическое значение", "Послелог *– это* служебное слово, выполняющее функцию предлога"?

Когда вроде бы и нужно "- это", но в то же время его можно опустить.

Про тире понятно. Вот интересует частица "это".

Answer (score 2):

"Послелог – это служебное слово, выполняющее функцию предлога".Никаких правил здесь и в подобных предложениях нет, это стилистика. Связка ЭТО(в школьной грамматике частица)в научном стиле желательна, в устной речи чаще всего пропускается, в публицистике и языке худ. литературы  смотрим на её функцию: степень выразительности и точность мысли предложения.Не потеряло смысла и эмоций без связки - пропускаем, потеряло-пишем.Сказывается тенденция к упрощению, лаконичности.

Comment: >Послелог – это служебное слово, выполняющее функцию предлога   
  
Людмила, простите, оффтопом. Вы эту абракадабру на содержательном уровне понимаете?
Послелог и послеслог (в болгарском, например) - это одно и то же? 
Интересно, во-первых, само по себе, а во-вторых, в плане гипотезы, что чем заумнее определение, тем больше хочется использовать разбираемое "это". В поледнее, впрочем, совсем не уверен.

Comment: Вы о том, что в русском языке их нет? Чистых нет, у нас только предлоги, но когда они стоят в постпозиции, иногда их называют послелогами:не корысти ради, а удовольствия для. Иногда чистым послелогом называют наречное слово НАЗАД и НАЗАД ТОМУ, ТОМУ НАЗАД   в выражениях  "неделю назад", "  недели три тому назад ", в школе говорят, что это наречный фразеологизм, но по сути послелог.

Comment: В татарском языке, наоборот, нет предлогов, а есть послелоги. Например, "Сказка о золотой рыбке" = "Алтын балык турында экият".  
Дословно переводится "Золотая рыба о сказка". Здесь "турында" = "о" - послелог.

Answer (score 1):

У меня тут есть две гипотезы. Во-первых, конструкция "- это" может быть эдакой заменой глагола-связки "есть" (от "быть"), потому что последний устаревает, но такая конструкция в научной, учебной, научно-публ. литературе является основной. То есть устаревшая форма переходит к более современной, не теряя в содержании. Во-вторых, это может быть попыткой "сэкономить" на интонации. Знаки препинания в устной речи так или иначе выделяются интонацией, логическими ударениями и так далее. То есть без "это" вышеуказанный пример должен звучать примерно так: "Послелог (пауза) служебное слово <...>". Если же там стоит "это", то можно говорить без паузы, не сбиваться с ритма, не прерываться, потому что "это" подразумевает наличие тире, но позволяет не выделять его интонационно.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую сочетание "- это" в определениях.

P.S. Cравните, употребление "=" и ":=" в некоторых языках программирования.

Comment: Это разные вещи. 
**:=** и **=** (как вариант **=** и **==** и проч.) используются чтобы различить операцию присваивания и логического сравнения. Здесь, в данной теме, ни о чем подобном речи не идет.

Comment: Верно, к теме эти операторы не относятся. Никак.

Comment: 1. Я знаю отличие между "=" и ":=". Также я знаю отличие между равенством и равенством по определению.

2.1 Я скажу: "Москва - столица России." Однако, я не скажу: "Москва - это столица России."

2.2 Я скажу: "Послелог - это предлог в постпозиции." Однако, я не скажу: "Послелог - предлог в постпозиции."

Comment: >Я знаю отличие  
  
Надо не только знать, но и уметь пользоваться. Во всяком случае, это отличие совсем не то, что <<между "=" и ":=">>.  

>>Однако, я не скажу  
  
А я скажу.

>>Однако, я не скажу  

А я скажу (типа припев).  
Т.е. я про послелог не скажу вообще. Ни так, ни эдак. Ибо мне это понятие неведомо. После**с**лог - это я знаю.
"Послеслог - артикль в постпозиции".

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы не видели отличие между предложениями "Баран - животное." и "Шкраб - это школьный работник.".

Answer (score 0):

О каких, простите, правилах Вы говорите?
"Это" можно опустить, можно не опускать. Вот и все правило.
Смотрите по стилистике, по ритму, как предлагалось...